# ¿Usar método abstracto sin definirlo?

Tags: java

Veamos el siguiente código, funciona, pero no comprendo por qué;

```
Toolkit miPantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Dimension tamañoPantalla = miPantalla.getScreenSize();
```

La clase Toolkit que solo hereda de Object y que pertenece al paquete java.awt es una clase abstracta, la razón entiendo que es porque contiene métodos abstractos (aka declarados pero no definidos)

Uno de esos métodos abstractos es;

```
abstract Dimension getScreenSize()
```

Mi duda es ¿Como es posible que usando el objeto miPantalla podamos ejecutar el método getScreenSize()? ¿No se supone que ese método, al ser abstracto, no está definido y que por lo tanto no contiene sentencias ni siquiera la sentencia return?

Gracias

Comment: por lo que leo en la documentacion, es abstracta, pero tiene codigo de lo lindo.. se supone que uno no la deberia llamar.. pero bue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La *firma* del método [`getDefaultToolkit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Toolkit.java#852) es como sigue:

```
public static synchronized Toolkit getDefaultToolkit() { ... }
```

De manera que es un método estático (**`static`**).

📖 Deitel (2012, p. 200) menciona que:

> Aunque la mayoría de los métodos se ejecutan en respuesta a llamadas de método sobre objetos específicos, esto no es siempre el caso. Algunas veces un método realiza una tarea que no depende del contenido de ningún objeto. Este método se aplica a la clase en la que se declara como un todo y se conoce como un método estático o un **método de clase**. Es común que las clases contengan métodos estáticos convenientes para realizar tareas comunes.

En otra parte (p. 74), también menciona:

> Un método estático es especial, porque se puede llamar sin crear primero un objeto de la clase en la que se declara el método.

💻 Adicionalmente, como menciona @Mikel, el método `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` retorna ya un objecto definido que extiende de `Toolkit`, por lo que es posible llamar a métodos como `getScreenSize()`. Esto puede verificarse con:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
System.out.println(toolkit.getClass().getName());
```

Si se ejecuta el código anterior en Windows (con `java.version=1.8.0_121`
), *imprimirá* [**`sun.awt.windows.WToolkit`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java), clase que extiende *a* [`sun.awt.SunToolkit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/SunToolkit.java) y ésta a su vez extiende *a* [`java.awt.Toolkit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Toolkit.java).

---

📓 ***Referencias***

Deitel, P. & Deitel, H. (2012). *Java : How to program.* Upper Saddle River, N.J: Prentice Hall.

Comment: La explicación luce genial, pero la pregunta es para el uso del método `getDimensionSize`

Comment: ¡Uy! Seguro estaba dormitando cuando leí la pregunta. :) Seguro es la falta de cafeína. Espero que @Mariano vea esto.

Comment: Creo que lo he entendido, getDefaultToolkit() devuelve un objeto de una clase que hereda de la clase Toolkit y que obligatoriamente ha redefinido el método getScreenSize al ser abstract. Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Castrol, si esta es la respuesta correcta, como mínimo deberías marcarla como tal (hay una marca de "Respuesta correcta" debajo del número de votos). Adicionalmente, si crees que lo merece, también puedes votar a favor (o en contra).

Comment: Gracias SJuan76, Ya la he marcado como correcta aunque la de Mikel ya lo dejaba claro. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

la funcion Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); retorna ya un objecto definido que extiende de Toolkit.
Declarar objetos abstractos y asinarle un objecto que extienda de la clase abstracto es común en java, por ejemplo:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Animal animal = new Gato();
       animal.saludar();

    }

}
abstract class Animal{
     abstract void saludar();
}

class  Gato extends Animal{

    @Override
    void saludar() {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo, miaw");
    }

}
```

Declaras un objecto Animal que va a ser un gato, despues de ese momento, no te debes de preocupar con que animal estas trabajando, solo necesitas saber que puede saludar, al llamar al metodo abstracto saludar, practicamente estas llamando al metodo saludar del objeco Gato.

Comment: OP tiene razon en algo.. getDefaultToolkit esta definido con codigo en la clase abstracta..

Comment: Gracias. Entiendo entonces que en este caso Toolkit declara el método como abstract pero también lo define ¿Donde puedo descargarme los archivos de las clases de la api de Java para poder leerlos?

Comment: cuando instalaste el JDK habia una opción que indicaba si deceabas incluir el   código fuente , creo que esta habilitado por defecto, deberia de tener un zip en donde instalaste el JDK, en mi caso esta es mi ruta : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\src.zip, si estas usando por ejemplo netbeans, puedes acceder a cualquier código fuente  dandole click a la funcion o clase pero  manteniendo  la tecla CTRL.

Comment: Gracias Mikel. Ya estoy leyendo la clase Toolkit y sus métodos getDefaultToolkit() y getScreenSize(). :-)

Comment: Ok suerte, esos códigos suelen ser complejos, pero a veces son de gran ayuda.